# Why s[0:4:-1] return nothing in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, slice

When `s = 'abcdefg'`, `s[0:4:-1]` and `s[1:-1:-1]` return nothing in Python3. However, `s[:4:-1]` returns `"gf"`. Could anyone explain the mechanism behind these two scenarios (especially in terms of memory)?

Comment: You might want to ready this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: I world argue it's not a perfect duplicate since it des not specifically exploits OP's cornercase

Comment: Hi @OlivierMelançon, I've read the thread, and don't think there is answer for my question.

MrGeek, as mentioned above, the thread can't answer why s[0:4:-1] return nothing, so I don't think this my question is duplicate.

Comment: @SidLin It actually does but very briefly. Please see my answer for a complete explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `start` is *always the first index* of the iteration.

The `stop` is the *end-boundary* of your iteration.

The `step` gives an *orientation* and a *step size* to the iteration. So the iteration always goes from `start` to `stop` in the direction given by the sign of `step`.

Thus `s[start:stop:step]` means to take the characters `s[start]`, `s[start + step]`, `s[start + 2 * step]`, ..., and so on until `stop` is reached.

In other words, `s[start:stop:-1]` is not equivalent to `reversed(s[start: stop])`.

### Examples

Thus in your example `s[0:4:-1]`, the is `step` negative so the iteration process immediately stops because the `start` index is already on the left of `stop.`

```
a b c d e f g h
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
^       ^
s       s
t       t
a       o
r       p
t

<-------- orientation
```

On the other end, if you were to try `s[4:0:-1]`, you would get `'edcb'` (remember that the `stop` index is excluded).

```
a b c d e f g h
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
^       ^
s       s
t       t
o       a
p       r
        t

<-------- orientation
```

Finally, leaving `start` empty means *from the end of the string*. This is why you see all characters from the end to index `4` in reverse.

```
a b c d e f g h
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
        ^     ^
        s     s
        t     t
        o     a
        p     r
              t

<-------- orientation
```

Comment: Note that aside from the canonical reversing slice (`[::-1]`) it's usually harder to interpret a slice running in reverse, so even though it's slightly less efficient, it's often a good idea to perform your slice as a forward slice, then reverse it, e.g. `x[:4][::-1]` rather than the faster, but harder to read equivalent, `x[3::-1]`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Actually, I agree with the readability issue. I'd even add that I usually prefer the even more readable `reversed(x[:4])` when an iterator is sufficient.